(Windows) Developing With Rust - Download Prebuilt Binaries - The term '%PATH%' is not recognized
I'm on this step: https://docs.solanalabs.com/cli/install#windows-1
I'm in the /solana-release dir. When I run set PATH=%cd%/bin;%PATH% in the Windows terminal (and I tried Powershell) as admin, it results in:
%PATH% : The term '%PATH%' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Any ideas?


Looking around at powershell docs, this might need to get updated to something like: $env:PATH += ";" + $pwd + "bin" 
